# javascript syntax error if AND statement

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

uck - keep getting syntax error - what's wrong?? - this was in my js console:
    var full_name = curry + ", " + stefan;
        if (( != None) && (!="") && (!= "None")) {
            full_name += " " + ;
        }
    add_html += "full_name";

The error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !=

Basically I'm trying to see if there is a middle initial or name that user inputted and add it to the nfull_name.  Here's the actual template code as well:

```
{% for each in allteachers %}
    var full_name = {{each.instructor_lastname}} + ", " + {{each.instructor_firstname}};
    if (({{each.instructor_middlename}} != None) && ({{each.instructor_middlename}}!="") && ({{each.instructor_middlename}}!= "None")) {
                full_name += " " + {{each.instructor_middlename}};
    }
    add_html += "<option value='{{each.key()}}'>full_name</option>";
```

{% endfor %}

Using jinaja2 - google app engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very very least, try surrounding your template variables with quotes:

```
{% for each in allteachers %}
    var full_name = "{{each.instructor_lastname}}" + ", " + "{{each.instructor_firstname}}";
    if (("{{each.instructor_middlename}}" != None) && ("{{each.instructor_middlename}}"!="") && ("{{each.instructor_middlename}}"!= "None")) {
            full_name += " " + "{{each.instructor_middlename}}";
    }
    add_html += "<option value='{{each.key()}}'>full_name</option>";
{% endfor %}
```

That will let you know if you're on the right track.

You need to be careful, though, because you're basically putting user input directly into your script code. This can be very dangerous -- the user who can submit the form can write whatever  JavaScript they want to in your page.

You should probably be validating this on the server, rather than trying to do it in client code. Then you can pass back values that you know are safe into your template.